# C-like #ifdef macros in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, compiling

The C programming language has a preprocessor, which has `#ifdef` `#endif` macros that allow to preprocess a source code file before the compilation process.

I am looking for something similar. What I actually want is being able to pass some variable straight to the compiler like so (it would compile text enabling some variable):

```
pdflatex mydocument.tex -DSOME_VARIABLE
```

Is there anything I could use? Again, all I want is conditional compiling and being able to pass some variable from the command line.

Comment: By "conditional compiling", are you referring to some condition used inside your document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document can look like:

```
...
\ifx\SOMEVARIABLE y
...
\else
...
\fi
...
```

and your command would be:

```
pdflatex '\let\SOMEVARIABLE=y \input' document
```